# Which is the best DNS Server solution for Windows Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

I'd like to move on Windows Server 2008 and could save 20 Euro every month if I am using Web Edition instead of the Standard Edition. The only "problem", Windows Server 2008 hasn't a build in DNS Server anymore.

Now I am asking me, which is the best third party DNS for my Webserver. I took a look on simpleDNS it seems quiet cool. Any additional idea or experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloadables/11). Plenty of documentation, and works just fine if you have time to learn.